# How to Hide and show a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I try to display a button that shows some text. Every X seconds the button must slide to the left and reappear with a new text inside.

Due to the other object on my page I can't use a popup.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

I already try with a grid, except that I don't find how to slide it.

**XAML**

```
   <Grid  x:Name="PropoCloud" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <tut:TutorialAwareButton Name="PropoButton"
                                         Style="{StaticResource tplButtonCloud}"
                                         Command="{Binding CmdCreated}"
                                         BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="410" Height="200">
            <tut:TutorialAwareButton.CommandParameter>
                <cmd:NavigationCommandParameter TargetName="QuestionCreatingView"></cmd:NavigationCommandParameter>
            </tut:TutorialAwareButton.CommandParameter>
        </tut:TutorialAwareButton>
    </Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private void SuggestionCycling()
{
    if (PropoCloud.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        PropoCloud.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        PropoCloud.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried implementing anything ? if so show us we might improve that

Comment: when is this called -- private void SuggestionCycling()

Comment: and I hope you know whats flow direction used for ?

Comment: The flow direction was used with a popup, this is just a mistake. And I call it in a button at the moment. I'll try to add a timer later.

Comment: This code works for me, when I click a button grid disappears and then click it reappears... whats at your end ?

Comment: I want it to slide on the left when it disappear, and on the right when it appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that you have posted will only hide and show the control back again, you need to have animation to fly it out and bring it in ... have a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278653/apply-animation-on-wpf-control-visibility-change) to understand how animation can do that...

The provided link is not for you to copy, make changes to suit your needs and understand the concept.

**This is a functionnal solution :**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FadeStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="FadeOut">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PropoCloud" Storyboard.TargetProperty="PropoCloud.Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="FadeIn">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PropoCloud" Storyboard.TargetProperty="PropoCloud.Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Just add the `FadeOut.Storyboard.Begin();`and `FadeIn.Storyboard.Begin();`In your timer cycle.

Comment: Your answer help me, I add the solution to it.